# Displaying data only relevant to the user logged in. Asp.net MVC5.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

I am starting work on a hobby project that simply keeps a list of contact information. Tons of tutorials out there but I am looking for individual based contact list. So when someone logs in using the simple log in provided, that user will only see contacts associated with him/her. Later on I would like to add OAuth but that is for another day.

How would I tie the relevant contact information to the specific log in information?

My data model looks like this:

```
namespace ContactManager.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

First I thought about having a column which associates a user with it. Something like storing the email of the user in a column with each contact info belonging to each user. But that seems like a lot of hassle.

Then I thought about having a table for each user. Which makes the database a bit cleaner but a lot of tables if there are a lot of users. I am not expecting a lot of users, I would just rather do it the "correct" way instead of some hack that assumes few users.

So again, how do I separate each users contact information so I can display the relevant info for each user?

Cheers!

P.S. I followed [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/) tutorial to start with and have that working to the extend that I need. (No OAuth login for example)

Comment: Why don't you just add the AspNetUser as virtal to your model? or the Id as a foreign key?

Comment: i think u need check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database

Comment: Please do not create a table for each user. Normalize your database - create a table for users and reference it from your Contacts table.

Comment: Asp.net already creates a table for my users called dbo.AspNetUsers. 
My contacts table is called dbo.Contacts. Would it make sense to make a column in my contacts table that is a foreign key pointing to my users table primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `User` table and a `UserContact` table. Assuming SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.User (
   UserId int identity(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   Name varchar(50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT UQ_User_Name UNIQUE,
   EmailAddress varchar(254)
);

CREATE TABLE UserContact (
   // Do NOT add a surrogate key to this table. No identity column!
   UserId int NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT FK_UserContact_UserId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.User(UserId),
   ContactId int NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT FK_UserContact_ContactId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Contact(ContactId),
   CONSTRAINT PK_UserContact PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserId, ContactId)
);
```

Then you link users to contacts by putting a row into this intermediate table with the IDs of the related entities (called a *many-to-many join table*).

One more thing to think about is that Users themselves have contact information. So you might consider doing this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.User (
   UserId int NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT FK_User_UserId_ContactId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE dbo.Contact(ContactId),
      CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);
```

This means that before anyone can be a user, their information must be entered as a contact first. Then, you insert the `ContactId` into the User table as their `UserId`. Finally, you use the same `UserContact` table with the same foreign key to this new `User` table. By doing it this way, you ensure that only people who have been marked as users in your system can be associated with contacts. You likely wouldn't want to be able to relate any contact to any other contact—the vast majority of your contacts won't be loggin into your system.

I frankly think this latter idea is a better scheme. It is called the "supertype/subtype" pattern, and is much like inheritance in structured programming, where a `Contact` can also be a `User`, and the `User` class inherits from the `Contact` class. You can even make this inheritance work exactly the same way in your code!

```
public class User : Contact {
}

var contact = GetSomeContact();
var user = contact as User;
if (user != null) {
    // This is a user! Do some special handling
}
```

You might also consider, instead, having them both inherit from a `Party` class (though possibly maintaining the "User is a subclass of Contact" relationship). If you put companies and organizations into your contact database, they also would be subclasses of the `Party` class. See [A Universal Person and Organization Data Model](http://tdan.com/a-universal-person-and-organization-data-model/5014) for some more ideas.

**Update**

Given the new information that you are using a pre-existing `dbo.AspNetUsers` table, you could either modify that table so it functions like the second `User` table I suggested above, or you could just omit the new `User` table, and use the `AspNetUsers` table as-is with the many-to-many join table pointing to it instead of to `User` as I suggested at first.

Comment: That sounds like the solution. How would I go about doing this without using the SQL you described. I am working with the entity framework and migrations take care of updating the database for me.  I have a table for my users called dbo.AspNetUsers and a contacts table which is called dbo.Contacts, as previously stated. I would like to add that foreign key to the Contacts table to point to the User table. BTW the migration automatically put ContactId as a primary key.

Comment: No, you wouldn't add a foreign key to the Contacts table to point to the User table. You can't do that without a many-to-many join table in between (unless you want each contact to be related to only one user, which I don't think is the case). I'm not an expert on Entity Framework, but you can search online for "many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework", and then follow instructions you find.

Comment: But my case is more like a single-to-many relationship. I want each user to have completely separate list of contacts. Since even though two or more users might have the same contact, the information in some of the columns is user dependent. Like a comment for example.

Comment: I was envisioning that you and, say, your spouse, would want to be able to share contacts, and have them both update if one of you makes a change. If you are sure that you would never want this, then you're right, just add the `UserId` to the `Contacts` table. One thing is that you can add more columns to the many-to-many join table that are specific to that user, so for example you and your spouse could share the same contact so if you update your dad's phone number, it's seen by both, but your comments on your dad are private (by being in the many-to-many table).

Comment: That feature where you share info between users, while being very valid and an awesome feature, will not be used by this application. At LEAST not in the foreseeable future.
So I will go ahead and try to link my tables together somehow... I guess I can just edit my contact model to include the foreign key in the Contacts table. Then the migration should take care of the rest. Here I go :)